# What should I do with my pg_log?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have two database server, one for main usage and the second is for standby. The log file is being recorded every day. About last week, when I found that my log file size is getting bigger and it used like 12GB disk space. I am wondering do I need to create a crontab schedule task like delete the old log like every 1 or two months. Will it affect my system or should I just do backup for it?

Another question is if I am doing streaming replication, the log file size of pg_log in standby server will be the same with primary server?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logfile-maintenance.html for some ideas of what you can do.

Personally, I think it's easiest to rotate logs cyclically, like what's described in this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133443. This method also can help you find what you're looking for more quickly, since your logs are separated by day. Of course, if you rotate logs based on the day name and have new logs overwrite the old, you're limiting the amount of time you can go back in the logs, which can be detrimental, but if you're consistently having to go back more than a week to check logs, you might need to get a more proactive monitoring system in place to alert you when problems are happening.

As for your second question, I don't have a definitive answer, but I'd expect that the log file sizes will be similar, but probably not exactly the same. Different servers might be setup with different logging verbosity, and there may be some log messages unique to each server.